# Is it possible to perform Delete and Update operations directly on External Database Tables, like in ORACLE, using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to know whether it is possible to delete the rows of the table in Oracle Database using Spark.
As,I want to use the same database table for the intermediate storage option,and once the batch operation is completed,the data inside it should be deleted but the table should be persisted.
Secondly,I want to run some update commands on the Oracle Database using Spark,so any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Did the answer help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

For mysql I use the following for an insert. Likewise you can build an appropriate update or delete statement. You need to set jdbc props, connections, etc.

I am assuming you mean this and not an append via DF/DS.write...

```
mutateStatement.execute (s"insert into sample (k,v) values(${val1}, ${val2})")
```

Note some persons correctly state that this could be subject to SQL injection and there is also prepared statement in batch updates which is safer. For example: [Using JDBC PreparedStatement.addBatch in functional Scala code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604563/using-jdbc-preparedstatement-addbatch-in-functional-scala-code)